# Добавление большого числа элементов в Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Нужно добавить 16 элементов связанных друг с другом в Dom используя ajax.

Сижу думаю как лучше сделать:

1. Серверная часть выдаёт готовый кусок html и я добавляю всё сразу 
   ($('html') и потом append() к нужному контейнеру).
2. Серверная часть выдаёт json с нужными данными и я собираю кусок DOM используя api jquery (методы createElement, add, addClass, attr).

Как я понимаю второй способ будет быстрее, но сложен в дальнейшей поддержке, так как элементов много и код создания ветки DOM получиться большим.
Может есть компромиссный способ?

Благодарю за советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 элементов - это это совсем не много, можно спокойно добавлять через `$('#container').html(htmlFromAjax);`

Всегда помните, [преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех бед](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science)#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Я правда не всё сказал, 16 элементов это за одну итерацию, а итераций может быть от 5 до 20.
Впрочему тут не оптимизация, а моя лень писать длинный код на с add, attr и тд.
Так или иначе я себя не уговорил и сделал первым способом, который можно легко поддерживать. Получилось достаточно быстро и удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще один способ: получить json и использовать шаблоны вывода html. Примерно так:

```
var list_s = '<ul>';
var list_e = '</ul>';
var list_i = '<li>%n%. %text%</li>';

//тут где-то Ajax запрос
function(data){
    var obj = JSON.decode(data), html = '', l = obj.length;

    html += list_s;
    for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i){
        html += list_i
            .replace('%n%', i)
            .replace('%text%', obj.text[i]);
    }
    html += list_e;

    $('#elem').html(html);
}
```

Comment: Для работы с шаблонами я бы посоветовал официальный плагин [jQuery Templates][1]

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/